# Statically link glib2

Tags: macos, dependencies, static-linking, glib

Is there any way to statically link glib2 to my binary? I am on a Mac OS X Lion.

If not, how someone suppose to develop an application that could be installed in a system not having glib libraries installed in their default location or not installed at all? In other words, distribution of binaries built with glib2 are for advanced users only, that know hot to download, build and install glib!? Where is the "Free software" spirit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any way to statically link GLib, but GIMP and GEdit (and other apps too) offer "normal" Mac OS X application bundles for download, so it's certainly possible to do it without static linking. [Here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/osx/README) are instructions on how GEdit does it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Can you confirm that already compiled dynamic libraries can change location, or I' ll have to build them from scratch too? (I'm referring to their **install_name**)?

Comment: I can't answer that, because I don't know how `gtk-mac-bundler` works internally. I would do as they suggest and compile everything yourself in a jhbuild environment.